# Tkinter windows floating in i3 but also working in MS-Windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, i3

I'm creating my first GUI app in Python using Tkinter. Very simple script to get some values from a python properties library based on user input. So nothing too complicated

The thing is I'm developing in Linux using i3. So I set `windows.attributes('type', 'dialog')` and works like a charm. However, in MS Windows, that line gives an error, and have to comment it.

Commented in i3, it still works, but the window is tilled, not floating.

Is there any way to make it floating in i3 and working in MS-Windows? Any window attributes that I might add to `.config/i3/config` to make it floaty and work on MS-Windows?

Thanks

MWE

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

    
window = tk.Tk()

window.title('pytiplier')
    
window.attributes(
    #THIS GIVES ERROR IN WINDOWS
    '-type', 'dialog',
)

frm_data = tk.Frame(relief=tk.GROOVE,
                    borderwidth=2,
                   )

frm_data.pack()

lbl_number = tk.Label(master=frm_data,
                      text='Enter a number:',
                      )

ent_number = tk.Entry(master=frm_data,
                      width=5,
                      )

lbl_number.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='e')
ent_number.grid(row=0,column=1)

frm_compute = tk.Frame()

btn_compute = tk.Button(master=frm_compute,
                        text="Compute!",
                        width=15,
                        height=2,
                        )

def compute_click(event):
    number = float(ent_number.get())
    result = np.pi*number
    lbl_result['text'] = f'\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PI}*{number} is {round(result, 4)}'


lbl_result = tk.Label(master=frm_compute,
                      width=40,
                      text='Enter a number and press Compute!'
                      )

lbl_result.pack()

btn_compute.bind("<Button-1>", compute_click)

btn_compute.pack()

frm_compute.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.overrideredirect(True)`? That removes the titlebar of the window.

Comment: No, I haven't. I like having the title bar and a floating window on i3. And on Windows, it must look similar to other apps, with the close window button. It will be used by other people, mostly windows user. So it must be natural to interact with. Thanks for the comment, I'll look into it, just as a learning tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there any way to make it floating in i3 and working in MS-Windows?*

If you need different behavior based on host OS, you might use [`platform.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system) from `platform` built-in module, consider simple example:

```
import platform
host = platform.system()
if host == "Linux":
    print("Running on Linux")
elif host == "Windows":
    print("Running on Windows")
else:
    print("Running on something else")
```

Comment: I added this and it's working. I perform the host check, and assign attributes based on this. Added a window.iconbitmap() to put a small icon custom on the corner. This icon is not shown on i3, as they are not defined in the WM. It looks really nice. Thanks!